# Revising loop-based Code in R

Tags: r

Assume a variable with 7 factors (`name_ttl`), each factor having a probability of being observed as described by `value_ttl_ben`(based on a training set). Now, assume that a vector of new observations comes in (`New_DNS`). I want to match the vector's 4th value (i.e. 5) with the probability value of factor level "5" (i.e. the level that matches the vector's specific value).
This is what I came up with but I was wondering how can I make this more efficient.

```
value_ttl_ben <- c(0.1428571, 0.2200000, 0.3928571, 0.1214286, 0.0785714, 0.0428571, 0.0014287)
name_ttl <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
BENIGN_TTL <- data.frame(Name=name_ttl, Amount=value_ttl_ben)
New_DNS <-c(36, 4, 3, 5, 4.68, 1.0056)
test1 <- as.matrix(BENIGN_TTL)
d <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(New_DNS[New_DNS %in% BENIGN_TTL$Name]))
{
  pos<-match(New_DNS[New_DNS %in% BENIGN_TTL$Name][i],test1)
  d<-c(d,test1[pos,2])
  d <- as.numeric(d)
} 
ttlb <- d[3]
```

Comment: It is not completly clear what you want, something like this seems to easy?! `BENIGN_TTL[ BENIGN_TTL$Name %in% New_DNS,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `%in%` to subset from BENIGN_TTL.

```
value_ttl_ben <- c(0.1428571, 0.2200000, 0.3928571, 0.1214286, 0.0785714, 0.0428571, 0.0014287)
name_ttl <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
BENIGN_TTL <- data.frame(Name=name_ttl, Amount=value_ttl_ben)
New_DNS <-c(36, 4, 3, 5, 4.68, 1.0056)

d<-BENIGN_TTL[BENIGN_TTL$Name %in% New_DNS,2]
```

Comment: This is indeed a neat and straight-forward solution. Depending what the OP wants/needs (straight forward vs. organised (F.e., I would prefer my solution as it organises the data more clearly)) he can choose either.

Comment: Yes @David. That is what I was after! Clarity and organization. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a so called `inner join`, which can be achievend by the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

value_ttl_ben <- c(0.1428571, 0.2200000, 0.3928571, 0.1214286, 0.0785714, 0.0428571, 0.0014287)
name_ttl <- 1:7
dt_benign_ttl <- data.table(Name = name_ttl, Amount = value_ttl_ben)

dt_new_dns <- data.table(Name = c(36, 4, 3, 5, 4.68, 1.0056))

# inner join merge
new_dt_new_dns <- merge(dt_benign_ttl, dt_new_dns, by = "Name")

new_dt_new_dns # contains the new DNS data in name and then adds the Amount from the dt_benign_ttl
# Name    Amount
# 1:    3 0.3928571
# 2:    4 0.1214286
# 3:    5 0.0785714
```

If you compare your `d`-variable (reordered by `New_DNS[New_DNS %in% BENIGN_TTL$Name]`) with my `new_dt_new_dns$Amount`, you should see that you get the same results.

Does that give you what you want/need?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly the same. I can then extract the value that I want. Great.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If this gives you the answer, please consider marking it as such!

Comment: How about computational-wise? This way would require less "effort" right?